# Is there a way in VB.NET to have buttons and menu bars that are built in the code show up in the design view?

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way in VB.NET to make components like buttons and menus bars show in design view of you added them in programmatically?

I now in Java i you add a button in the code it will show in design view if you switch back and forth. Can this be done in VB.NET.

Code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'defining the main menu bar
        Dim mnuBar As New MainMenu()
        'defining the menu items for the main menu bar
        Dim myMenuItemFile As New MenuItem("&File")
        Dim myMenuItemEdit As New MenuItem("&Edit")
        Dim myMenuItemView As New MenuItem("&View")
        Dim myMenuItemProject As New MenuItem("&Project")

        'adding the menu items to the main menu bar
        mnuBar.MenuItems.Add(myMenuItemFile)
        mnuBar.MenuItems.Add(myMenuItemEdit)
        mnuBar.MenuItems.Add(myMenuItemView)
        mnuBar.MenuItems.Add(myMenuItemProject)

        ' defining some sub menus
        Dim myMenuItemNew As New MenuItem("&New")
        Dim myMenuItemOpen As New MenuItem("&Open")
        Dim myMenuItemSave As New MenuItem("&Save")

        'add sub menus to the File menu
        myMenuItemFile.MenuItems.Add(myMenuItemNew)
        myMenuItemFile.MenuItems.Add(myMenuItemOpen)
        myMenuItemFile.MenuItems.Add(myMenuItemSave)

        'add the main menu to the form
        Me.Menu = mnuBar

        ' Set the caption bar text of the form.  
        Me.Text = "tutorialspoint.com"

        'create a new TreeView
        Dim TreeView1 As TreeView
        TreeView1 = New TreeView()
        TreeView1.Location = New Point(5, 30)
        TreeView1.Size = New Size(150, 150)
        Me.Controls.Add(TreeView1)
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
        'Creating the root node
        Dim root = New TreeNode("Application")
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root)
        TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("Project 1"))
        'Creating child nodes under the first child
        For loopindex As Integer = 1 To 4
            TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(New  _
                TreeNode("Sub Project" & Str(loopindex)))
        Next loopindex
        ' creating child nodes under the root
        TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("Project 6"))
        'creating child nodes under the created child node
        For loopindex As Integer = 1 To 3
            TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(1).Nodes.Add(New  _
                TreeNode("Project File" & Str(loopindex)))
        Next loopindex
        ' Set the caption bar text of the form.  
        Me.Text = "tutorialspoint.com"
    End Sub

    Private Sub openInWeb()
        Try
            Dim url As String = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
            Process.Start(url)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("There's something wrong!")
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
        fileReader =
        My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Asnreiu3.txt")
        Dim stringReader As String
        stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
        MsgBox("The first line of the file is " & stringReader)
        openInWeb()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing
        Dim openFileBox As New OpenFileDialog()

        openFileBox.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
        openFileBox.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        openFileBox.FilterIndex = 2
        openFileBox.RestoreDirectory = True

        If openFileBox.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                myStream = openFileBox.OpenFile()
                If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                    ' Insert code to read the stream here. 
                    '**************************
                    ' your code will go here  *
                    '**************************
                End If
            Catch Ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
            Finally
                If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                    myStream.Close()
                End If
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim myStream As Stream
        Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                ' Code to write the stream goes here.
                myStream.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolTip1_Popup(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PopupEventArgs) Handles ToolTip1.Popup

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button(p1 As Object)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

    Private Function myButton() As Windows.Forms.Button
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        AboutBox1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim lbl As New Label
        lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23) 'set your size (if required)
        lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 190) 'set your location
        lbl.Text = "You just clicked button 5" 'set the text for your label
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl)  'add your new control to your forms control collection
    End Sub

    Public Sub HellowWorld()
        MsgBox("Hello World!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        HellowWorld()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        Dim ProgressBar1 As ProgressBar
        Dim ProgressBar2 As ProgressBar
        ProgressBar1 = New ProgressBar()
        ProgressBar2 = New ProgressBar()
        'set position
        ProgressBar1.Location = New Point(10, 200)
        ProgressBar2.Location = New Point(10, 250)
        'set values
        ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 200
        ProgressBar1.Value = 130
        ProgressBar2.Minimum = 0
        ProgressBar2.Maximum = 100
        ProgressBar2.Value = 40
        'add the progress bar to the form
        Me.Controls.Add(ProgressBar1)
        Me.Controls.Add(ProgressBar2)
        ' Set the caption bar text of the form.  
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The Designer does only show Controls that are created in the FormName.Designer.vb file. It does not run code in the FormName.vb file. When adding controls in the Designer, they are added to the `InitializeComponent()` method in the FormName.Designer.vb file.

So the only way to show the controls in the Designer is to add them in the Designer or to edit the FormName.Designer.vb file manually. If you decide for the latter, you should mimic the code that is generated by the Designer very closely in order to avoid problems when the Designer is shown. Also, be prepared that the Designer regards the FormName.Designer.vb file as completely generated code and might decide to recreate the file sooner or later omitting parts that it cannot handle.

Side note: in order to see the FormName.Designer.vb file, you should select "Show All Files" for the project in Solution Explorer.